# My Custom theme not applied in magento?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I am new to magento, I have created custom theme(test) and I copied the all (layout,template and skin) default source code paste it my theme. And I have selected the admin panel my theme which is Test, but it's not applying.

can any one tell me where I went wrong?

see below images which is I have created and selected themes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Template files should be under `app/design/frontend/your_package/default/template`

Comment: hi pspahn, what about layout files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder in `app/local` has nothing to do with your theme.
Your template & layout files need to be placed in `app/design/frontend/test/default/template/` and `app/design/frontend/test/default/layout/`.
Your js, css and images need to be placed in `skin/frontend/test/default/`.
After having these set up you need to set in `System->configuration->design` the `Current package name` to `test` (lowercase letter).
Save and clear the cache.
If you don't want to use `default` as the theme folder (but it's better if you do) you can change the folders above to
`app/design/frontend/test/{theme_name}/template/`
`app/design/frontend/test/{theme_name}/layout/`
`skin/frontend/test/{theme_name}/`.
if you do this then you have to set in `System->Configuration->Design->Themes` the field `Default` to `{theme_name}`. (Don't use curly brackets. They are there just as placeholders).
[Read this for more info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/)